# How to detect right click of mouse on the button?

Tags: c++, winapi

Need to detect right click of mouse on the button.

Comment: Personally, I've never heard about mouse in Android.

Comment: Are you writing a console program or windows application?

Comment: By "on the button" do you mean you have a button control and you want to detect a right-click on it?

Comment: Do you want your program interrupted when the mouse button is pressed or do you want to wait for a button press?

Comment: Thomas Matthews, I writing windows application. I want something like this, when I clicked right button of mouse on the button will be call function.

Comment: just looked MFC and not found a similar, perhaps that click is not handled on the button, but thanks for the reply.

Comment: You need to explain what "on the button" means.

Comment: Jonathan Potter, I mean that you write. Button control and I want to detect a right-click on it

Comment: Im write answer - HERE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318911/detect-if-mouse-button-is-down/40470665#40470665

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are typically two approaches with the basic WinAPI. The most common for applications tends to be synchronous, which means you need to process [WM_RBUTTONDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [WM_RBUTTONUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages in your message handler. It's useful because you don't need to keep querying the mouse buttons all the time. Your program just needs to respond appropriately when the events arrive.

However, if you're making something like a game, then asynchronous is sometimes preferred. It lets you query whether the mouse button is up or down at any given moment by calling [GetAsyncKeyState()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It can be useful if your program design is centred around a primary update loop architecture.

Comment: The problem is that when I clicked on the button, message like as WM_RBUTTONDOWN doesn't work

Comment: When you click on a button the WM_RBUTTONDOWN message goes to the button, not to its parent window. You can subclass the button to sense that message.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at [WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646241%28VS.85%29.aspx), [WM_RBUTTONDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [WM_RBUTTONUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).