# Check if left mouse button is held down?

Tags: c++, winapi

So I am just getting myself into coding using C++ and after learning a bit I started coding an auto clicker. I have already made it so you can toggle the auto clicker using a button on your keyboard or something of that sort, but that isn't what I'm looking for.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to find a way to check if the left mouse button is held down. If it is held down, then keep on clicking until the left mouse button is no longer held.

Also, I have looked around a lot to see how to do this, and I have gotten a few different things I should do, but none of them work. I was told to use:

```
if((GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x100) != 0)
```

from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18318977/11224556), but I also found that people were told to use:

```
if(GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x8000
```

Sadly I can't find where I found this in my history.

1. I have tried getting the key state of **WM_LBUTTONDOWN** but it doesn't seem to pick up the mouse button is being pressed.
2. I can get it working by checking the key state of **VK_LBUTTON**, but that only checks to see if the left mouse button has been pressed, not held. So it just continuously clicks until you break the while loop or close the program.
3. Not really worth putting this down but my 12 am self, thought that checking if the left button had been pressed (like the one before), it would set a boolean value to true and then keep on clicking. But after that, I couldn't get it to stop like before. Now looking back at the code, I understand why it wasn't working.

```cpp
while (1) {
   if(GetKeyState(WM_LBUTTONDOWN)) {

      Sleep(delay);
      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
      std::cout << "Clicked" << endl;
   }

   if (GetKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)) {

      break;
   }

}
```

Like I said before, I have tried all different combinations to try and get this to work. But I can't see if the left mouse button is held down. I hope someone has the answer and can help me out and other people out. Anyways, thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: Hi exro, is the issue solved? If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) helped you or post your own solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GetKeyState()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate) takes a [virtual key code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) as input, but [`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-lbuttondown) is not a virtual key code, it is a window message.  Use `VK_LBUTTON` instead.

Also, `GetKeyState()` relies on a state machine that is local to the calling thread.  That state machine is updated only when the thread processes keyboard/mouse window messages from its message queue.  Your code has no such message processing.  For what you are attempting, use [`GetAsyncKeyState()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) instead.

Also, [`mouse_event()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event) is deprecated and has been for a long time.  Use [`SendInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead.

Try this:

```cpp
while (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) >= 0)
{
   if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0)
   {
      Sleep(delay);

      INPUT input[2] = {};

      input[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
      input[0].mi.dx = x;
      input[0].mi.dy = y;
      input[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;

      input[1] = input[0];
      input[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;

      SendInput(2, input, sizeof(INPUT));

      std::cout << "Clicked" << endl;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I understood the q correctly .. but for checking the pressed state you have always to check the lowest bit in the returned high-byte of `GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)` (see [GetKeyState() in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate?redirectedfrom=MSDN)-- means:

`bool leftButtonPressed = 0 != (GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x800);`

`WM_LBUTTONDOWN` is the message that is send to a window reporting a Left-button-down-event in the client area -- so using that in the GetKeyState() function is wrong. Try

```
const int delay = 50;
while (1) 
{
  if (GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x800)
  {
    Sleep(delay);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0,0, 0, 0);
    std::cout << "Clicked" << std::endl;
  }

  if (GetKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) & 0x800)
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I just tried that, it still only prints "Clicked" once even though I'm holding down the left click.

Comment: but that `mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0,0, 0, 0);` sets the key back to "not pressed" -- means the `if (GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x800)`says "false" and waits for the next click in the while loop. So you have to click again.

Comment: Ohhhh ok. I think I might know how to fix it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The code below prints the "clicked" as long as the button is pressed:

    `while ((GetKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) & 0x800) == 0) 
    {
      if (GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x800)
      {
        Sleep(delay);
        std::cout << "Clicked" << std::endl;
      }
    }`

Comment: `GetKeyState()` returns a `SHORT` (a 16-bit signed integer), where the high bit is 1 if the key is down. But `0x800` does not represent the high bit, `0x8000` does. Rather than using `GetKeyState(...) & 0x8000` to test for down, you can use `GetKeyState(...) < 0` instead (and likewise `GetKeyState(...) >= 0` to test for up).