# SendInput Mouse input click only?

Tags: c++, winapi

How can I make a mouse input with SendInput()? I am entirely confused, I don't understand what it is saying on Microsoft's website. Here is my current code:

```cpp
if (toggled && (GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x100))
{
    SendInput(UINT, MOUSEINPUT, WM_LBUTTONUP, NULL);
    Sleep((rand() % 1000 / cps));
}
```

Comment: i dont understand what goes inside the parameters up sendinput.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fill out an (array of) [`INPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-input) struct(s) containing the mouse details you want, and then you pass that array to `SendInput()`. This is pretty clearly explained in the [`SendInput()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput):

> Parameters
>
> `cInputs`
>
> Type: `UINT`
>
> The number of structures in the `pInputs` array.
>
> `pInputs`
>
> Type: `LPINPUT`
>
> An array of `INPUT` structures. Each structure represents an event to be inserted into the keyboard or mouse input stream.
>
> `cbSize`
>
> Type: `int`
>
> The size, in bytes, of an `INPUT` structure. If `cbSize` is not the size of an `INPUT` structure, the function fails.

Also, your call to `GetKeyState()` is wrong, as it will never return a `SHORT` value that has its 9th bit set to 1.  Per the [`GetKeyState()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate), only the low (1st) bit or the high (16th) bit will ever be set to 1:

> The return value specifies the status of the specified virtual key, as follows:
>
> - If the high-order bit is 1, the key is down; otherwise, it is up.
> - If the low-order bit is 1, the key is toggled. A key, such as the CAPS LOCK key, is toggled if it is turned on. The key is off and untoggled if the low-order bit is 0. A toggle key's indicator light (if any) on the keyboard will be on when the key is toggled, and off when the key is untoggled.

So, if your goal is to check if the left mouse button is currently held down, you need to use `& 0x8000` (or `< 0`) instead of `& 0x100` (even better, consider using `GetAsyncKeyState()` instead).  See [Check if left mouse button is held down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58029712/).

Try this instead:

```cpp
if (toggled && (GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0 /*& 0x8000*/))
{
    INPUT input = {};
    input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
    Sleep((rand() % 1000 / cps));
}
```