# c++ - How would I detect if the middle button is held down?

Tags: c++, windows-10, mouselistener

Is it possible to detect if the middle button is being held down in c++? I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318911/detect-if-mouse-button-is-down) question, but it did not mention anything about listening for buttons except the left mouse button.

I want

```
int main(){
    while (1){
        while((GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x100) != 0){
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Sleep(10);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but instead of triggering when the left button is pressed, triggering when the middle button is pressed.

Comment: for that you have to consult with your OS API.

Comment: C++ has no concept of a mouse. If you need it in a specific environment, operating system etc please add that information to the question and tags

Comment: So, when you looked through the code in the other question, did you understand what it does? Have you googled each of the functions to understand them? Try googling the functions in that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifically asking about how to do something for the middle mouse button which you have only found explained for the left mouse button. (At least you stress that very much, though I do not see how the shown code is applicable....)

So when searching for `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN` and `VK_LBUTTON` I found that e.g. here, they are listed among very promising siblings, especially `MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN` and `VK_MBUTTON`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

Since you only ask about the difference between left and middle, you should be set with this information.